# Missing Exercises in Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, online-resources

I'm a beginner in math and I just started studying Elementary Number Theory by Dudley. So far I'm impressed, but I've noticed that the book does not include all the solutions to the exercises they present in the chapters, namely those that require you to prove some property.

I would really like to find the worked out solutions to all the exercises. I've looked all over for a solution to all the exercises with no luck. Perhaps I'm missing something or perhaps someone knows a source I could use?

Thank You

Comment: ...or perhaps there are no online solutions to that book's exercises, so that the best source you could use is your brains.

Comment: Numerical questions will have a unique correct answer, but "prove" questions will have so many correct answers that providing one would be pretty useless. If your answer differed from the one provided, you would have no idea whether your answer was wrong, or just different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a published instructors guide to go with Dudley's text, which includes some nice commentary as well as exercise solutions. Dover has it posted online: [Instructors Guide to Elementary Number Theory](http://www.doverpublications.com/solutions/46931x.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

[My comment has been well-received, so I'll risk elevating it to an answer]

Numerical questions will have a unique correct answer, but "prove" questions will have so many correct answers that providing one would be pretty useless. If your answer differed from the one provided, you would have no idea whether your answer was wrong, or just different.